# How to get Javascript to "communicate" with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, communication

I have the following code (PHP):

```
  $link = array(
    "<ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="whatwedo.html">What We Do</a></li>
          <li><a href="howitworks.html">How It Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="lalalala_hiding_paypal_url_details">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>",
    "<p>hi</p>",
    "<img src="images/illy.png" />",
    "<a href="index.html">go to index</a>",
    "<h3>blah</h3>",
    "<p>yipeeeeeeeee!</p>");

    // Choose a random piece.
    $i = sizeof($link);
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

    // Show random piece.
    $result = $link[rand(0,$i - 1)];
```

The above is inside a PHP file.

I have another file (HTML File) which includes:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://website.net/myphpfile.php'>
</script>
```

And I would like to display in **pure** javascript the `$result` of the PHP function where ever the javascript scripts tags are placed.

Is there anyway I can do this easily?

Comment: myphpfile.php is not a javascript file. You have to write javascript codes in the file provided in <script> tag. Or you can dinamically generate using php file. But your provided php file generates nothing.

Comment: I KNOW myphpfile.php is NOT a javascript file. You obviously misunderstood something I said.

Comment: Just curious, and not very relevant.. but what is it you're doing inside that PHP file? Wouldn't it be simpler to just do $result = $link[array_rand($link)]; ?

Answer (score 0):

Just make myphpfile.php echo javascript code.

```
echo "var x=171;";
echo "alert(x+' the number');";

OR

$js=<<<JAVASCRIPT
var t=10100;
alert(t);
JAVASCRIPT;
echo $js;
```

Comment: huh..? why not just `?>var t=10100; alert(t);<?php`? Why mess around with strange constructs for something PHP was designed to do?

Comment: @j-t-s: try it this way: `<?php echo "alert($result);" ?>`

Comment: doesn't alert display a messagebox? would document.write work that way too? (thank you)

Comment: Still nothing with "alert($result);".

Comment: @j-t-s: yes alret displays a box. We dont really know how you want to use the data youre writing out so alert is a generic example that lets you see if the data or whatever is there for use. You would most likely replace this with  a simple `var fromPhp = thephpvalue;` or a function call or something. no document.write will write whatever to the document as its name implies. You are jsut sticking this php code on to the end of the file you quoted in your question as opposed to replacing it all, right?